# django + celery - How do I set up a crontab schedule for celery in my django app?

Tags: django, celery, cron

I am following the instructions here:

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

I'm supposed to be able to do the following:  `from celery.schedules import crontab`

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
from kombu import serialization
serialization.registry._decoders.pop("application/x-python-serialize")
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
from celery.schedules import crontab

...

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'first_task': {
        'task': 'apps.icecream.tasks.sync_flavors',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/30', hour='1, 3, 6, 8-20, 22')
    },
    'second_task': {
        'task': 'apps.robots.tasks.run_robots',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/6')
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error: "No module named schedules"

If I switch to the other way of scheduling, using timedelta, then everything is fine and I can get my periodic tasks to run:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'first_task': {
        'task': 'apps.icecream.tasks.sync_flavors',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=30)
    },
    'second_task': {
        'task': 'apps.robots.tasks.run_robots',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=6)
    }
}
```

Why can't I use the crontab approach?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This happens because you have a `celery.py` file in the same package as your `settings.py`, which shadows the global `celery` package.

To get around this, insert the following string at the beginning of the settings.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Because in the same folder where has located settings.py you have a file celery.py which conflicts with a "celery" package.

Comment: @AlbertTugushev Provide some explanation to your solution and why it works.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: Also remember to remove `pyc` files. I had a `celery.pyc` that caused this error.

Comment: yah ! it worked, thanks, thanks for the explanation!